# JavaScript redirect just before submitting form and opening new tab

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

I have a situation where I need to open a new tab to an external site when the user clicks "submit" on a form, and at the same time I need to redirect the original tab to a different page to prevent the user making multiple duplicate requests to the external site.

**NOTE:** I *have* protected against this behaviour in the back-end, I just want to use JavaScript to improve the UX where possible, removing the rendering of the option in the first place.

**NOTE2:** This works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari.

Some example code which illustrates my issue is shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testFunction(){
        alert("Executing testFunction()!");
        window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
    }
    // uncomment this line to show that testFunction() does work when called directly
    //testFunction();
</script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS Redirect Then Post Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="POST" target="_blank">
                First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
                Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="testFunction()">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click submit, I observe the alert popping up, but the redirect does not execute.

If I uncomment the line which calls testFunction() directly, it works as expected.

How can I get the behaviour I'm looking for?

Comment: On Firefox when I press "Submit" it opens a new tab (on the same page) and the original tab goes to Google. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Ah! You're right, it works in Firefox. Ironically, not in Chrome :-) I shall edit the question, thanks.

Comment: Can you try replacing "replace" with simple assignment? window.location = "http://www.google.com"

Comment: Still doesn't work Freeman.

Comment: use window.location.href="";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I managed to come up with after a bit of tinkering around. You can pass the click event from onclick into your handler function. If you let the event happen, it will just submit the form and prevent all following execution, that is why I stopped the original click event with `preventDefault` and triggered `form.submit()` programmatically.
Also notice how I wrapped the redirect inside a `setTimeout` to give time to the `submit()` to actually happen before the redirect.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testFunction(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.target.parentNode.submit();
            alert("Executing testFunction()!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
            }, 0);

        }
        // uncomment this line to show that testFunction() does work when called directly
        // testFunction();
    </script>
    <title>JS Redirect Then Post Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" target="_blank">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="testFunction(event)">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bloody marvellous, sir. Thank you :-)